# Is window.innerWidth safe before window.onload?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious where it is safe to place any of these

```
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;
```

Must they go inside a `window.onload = function(){};` to be trusted?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-window-innerwidth, `window.innerWidth` does not depend on the page contents or layout but rather on the [viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport) size.

Answer (score 0):

You kinda have two questions. The answer to the question in your title is **yes, `window.innerWidth` is safe before `window.onload`**.

However, the question in your description, as to whether or not that posted code is completely safe **is not necessarily the same**.

For instance, let's say you have that code snippet in the head of your document and your browser's width is 0. In this case, your provided code will end up evaluating all three properties and once it attempts to evaluate `document.body.clientWidth` you will get a **TypeError** breaking execution of your script since, at this point in your document, there is no `document.body`.

Indeed, a small/edge case, but in the short of things your *posted code is not always safe*.